# DateTimeOffset value changing

Tags: sql-server, ssis, datetimeoffset

I'm moving data that is currently been stored as a `int to DateTimeOffset`.

Example here is the starting value 1341190841 and when I use this query :

```
dateadd  (s,Call.StartTime, '1970-01-01') AS StartTimeDate
```

It returns this value `2012-07-02 01:00:41.000` which is correct. However I'm using SSIS to move data from one db to another and when the data is in the new table the `StartTimeDate` now looks like this `2012-07-02 01:00:41.0000000 +01:00`.

Anyone got any idea how to remove the +01:00? I want to keep the time as it is in the first query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wasn't able to reproduce that behaviour (even with two SQL Servers in different timezones), so this may not be exactly what you want, but you can "fix" the TZ offset (the "+01:00") after copying the data by updating the `StartTimeDate` column with the function [`ToDateTimeOffset`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630335%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) like this:

```
UPDATE the_table SET StartTimeDate = TODATETIMEOFFSET(StartTimeDate, 0)
```

That will leave the date and time untouched while adjusting the offset to the specified one (`0` since you want it to "adjust" the TZ from +1 to 0).